# SwiftUI contextMenu shows previous value

Tags: swift, contextmenu, swiftui

I am having a weird issue with SwiftUI ContextMenu, most probably a bug, but maybe someone else have found a workaround for it. I simplified it to this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number = 20
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Test")
                }
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.number > 0 {
                    self.number -= 1
                }
            }
    }
}
```

When the contextMenu appears for the first time, the correct number is displayed. 
But when the second time the contextMenu appears, it still shows the first value of the contextMenu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlUSq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following tricks to make the count persistent.

```
        @State var number : Int = 20
 @State var showNUmber : Bool = true
   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

   var body: some View {
    Group{
    if self.showNUmber {
    Text("\(self.number)").padding()
                           .background(Color.green)
        .contextMenu{
               Button(action: {
               }) {
                   Image(systemName: "star")
                   Text("Test")
            }
        }.onLongPressGesture( pressing: { _ in
                        self.showNUmber = false
        }, perform: {
        })
    }else{

Text("\(self.number)").padding()
                                     .background(Color.green)
                  .contextMenu{
                         Button(action: {


                         }) {
                             Image(systemName: "star")
                             Text("Test")
                      }
                  }.onLongPressGesture( pressing: { _ in
                                  self.showNUmber = true
                  }, perform: {
                  })
        }
    }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
        if self.number > 0 {
            self.number -= 1
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly in this case. The problem is that in my code I have a onTapGesture too and with this workaround the onTapGesture don't work.